# Swift - JSON Response Begins with \u201c and end with \u201d

Tags: php, ios, json, swift

I have a Swift script whose intent right now is to first, send a JSON string to a PHP file; second, return the values sent to the php script parsed in the XCODE console; third return one of the values below below.  However, my string returns values that begin with \u201C and end with \u201d.

Can someone please let me know first, why it's doing that and second, how to resolve it?

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        let myUrl = NSURL(string: "http://localhost/phpPost/demo.php");
        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: myUrl!);
        request.HTTPMethod = "POST";



let postString = "firstName=James&lastName=Bond";

request.HTTPBody = postString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding);

let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithRequest(request) {
    data, response, error in
    if error != nil {
        println("error=\(error)")
        return
    }
    println("******response = \(response)")

    // Print out response body
    let responseString = NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)
    println("****response data=\(responseString)")

    //Let’s convert response sent from a server side script to a NSDictionary object:

    var err: NSError?
    var myJSON = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: .MutableLeaves, error:&err) as? NSDictionary

    if let parseJSON = myJSON {
        var firstNameValue = parseJSON["firstName"] as? String
        println("firstName: \(firstNameValue)")
    }

}
task.resume()
```

Also, here's the PHP:

```
<?php
$firstName= $_REQUEST["firstName"];
$lastName = $_REQUEST["lastName"];// Store values in an array
$returnValue = array(“firstName”=>$firstName, “lastName”=>$lastName);
// Send back request in JSON format
echo json_encode($returnValue); 
?>
```

Here is what is returned:

****response data=Optional({"\u201cfirstName\u201d":"James","\u201clastName\u201d":"Bond"})
firstName: nil

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look closely at what you have posted here. Compare the quotes in `$returnValue` in PHP to the quotes on the two lines before. You are using curly quotes instead of simple double-quotes.

You have:

```php
$returnValue = array(“firstName” => $firstName, “lastName” => $lastName);
```

You want:

```php
$returnValue = array("firstName" => $firstName, "lastName" => $lastName);
```

Comment: That works great - I appreciate that.  Began to figure that it was an issue with the PHP and not the swift but couldn't put my finger on it.